# Put all dataframes with names containing a particular string into a single list

Tags: r, list, function

I am trying to write a function that makes a list of dataframes that contain a certain string.

If I write:

```
objlist <- ls(pattern = "*_results*")
all_dfs <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) any(class(get(x)) == 'data.frame'))]
dfs_list <-  mget(Reduce(intersect, list(objlist, all_dfs)))
```

"dfs_list" contains all the dataframes in the environment that contain "_results" (in my particular case it creates a list of 20 dataframes).

However if I try to convert it to a function:

```
list_dataframes <- function(pattern) {
  objlist <- ls(pattern = pattern)
  all_dfs <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) any(class(get(x)) == 'data.frame'))]
  dfs_list <-  mget(Reduce(intersect, list(objlist, all_dfs)))  
  return(dfs_list)
}

flarp <- list_dataframes("*_results*")
```

The object "flarp" is a list of 0 elements.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the function creates another "function environment", and since you call `ls()` from within this function, you will have the list of objects existing within this function. Please consider the following code which sould be clear.

```
print(ls()) # Globalenv objects
test <- function() { #different envir inside a function
  a <- "test"
  print(ls())
} 
test() # only prints "a" 
test <- function() {
  print(ls(.GlobalEnv))
}
test() # prints all the globalenv objects
```

Actually, functions use up to as many as **four types of environments**: enclosing, binding, execution and calling. You can learn more in [this in-depth Chapter of Avanced R by Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Comment: Thanks, I added an argument for the environment that defaults to .GlobalEnv and put it as an argument to the ls() and mget() calls. It appears to be working now!

Answer (score 3):

That's because of `ls()`. When you put it in a function you need to specify the environment explicitly, either by `name`, `pos` or `env` arguments, i.e.

```
f1 <- function() ls()
f1()
#character(0)

f1 <- function() ls(pos = 1)
f1()
#[1] "df" "f1" "rb"
```